# Java Regex/Split without lose characters

Tags: java, regex

I have this String:

```
String str = "Filtración con membrana - Nanofiltración Ósmosis inversa Desinfección";
```

and I want to get an array with these elements:

```
["Filtración con membrana - Nanofiltración", "Osmosis inversa", "Desinfección"]
```

I'm splitting this way:

```
String[] elements = str.split("[a-zà-ú] [A-ZÀ-Ú]");
```

But I'm getting this array, instead:

```
["Filtración con membrana - Nanofiltració", "osmosis invers", "esinfección"]
```

What can I do? I only want remove the space (" ") in the split but not the characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why doesnt `[a-zà-ú] [A-ZÀ-Ú]` work?**

The issue with the regex is that the character classes at the two sides of the space will consume one character each. So the split function will indeed take away those two characters that matches the regex and would not be included in the output

**Solution**

Instead of using the regex as such, try look arounds instead

```
String[] elements = str.split("(?<=[a-zà-ú]) (?=[A-ZÀ-Ú])");
```

- `(?<=[a-zà-ú])` Look behind assertion. Checks if the space is presceded by the characters in the class. But this ***won't*** consume the character.
- `(?=[A-ZÀ-Ú])` Look ahead assertion. Checks if the space if followed by any of these characters.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bH8aT0/1)

**Test**

```
String str = "Filtración con membrana - Nanofiltración Ósmosis inversa Desinfección";
String[] elements = str.split("(?<=[a-zà-ú]) (?=[A-ZÀ-Ú])");
for (String i : elements)
    System.out.println(i);
```

will give an output as

```
Filtración con membrana - Nanofiltración
Ósmosis inversa
Desinfección
```

Comment: Perfectly explained. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
String str = "Filtración con membrana - Nanofiltración Ósmosis inversa Desinfección";
String[] toks = str.split( "(?<=\\p{javaLowerCase}) +(?=\\p{javaUpperCase})" );
for (String tok: toks)
    System.out.printf("=> <%s>%n", tok);
```

#### Output:

```
=> <Filtración con membrana - Nanofiltración>
=> <Ósmosis inversa>
=> <Desinfección>
```

This regex is matching 1 or more spaces and using a lookahead pattern `(?=\\p{javaUpperCase})` which means space must be followed by a unicode uppercase letter. It is also using a lookbehind `(?<=\\p{javaLowerCase})` which means space must be preceded by a unicode lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks! it works, I'm newbie and I didn't that is possible call "java methods" inside regex. I really must go over regex :)

Comment: `javaLowerCase` and `javaUpperCase` are not Java methods. These are regex properties for unicode letters.

Comment: I didn't know how to name them, thanks. But, are they available in another language? I mean, are they standard?

Comment: Yes they are available in PCRE also but with a different name.